# Which other Azure services do I need to take into account when using Azure Spatial Anchors?

Tags: azure, azure-spatial-anchors

I would like to use Azure Spatial Anchors and understand that it is free during the preview period.

1. Are there other Azure services like storage, bandwidth, etc. involved which I would need to take into consideration regarding pricing when working with Azure Spatial Anchors?
2. Does anyone have a rough estimate how much it costs to work with a "typical" Azure Spatial Anchors project? I know this is a broad question but if someone could give me a rough estimate from their experience I'd be more than happy!

Answer (score 1):

While in preview, Azure Spatial Anchors is free ([pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/spatial-anchors/)).

Depending on your project, you may need to use other cloud services, which may or may not also be free. For example, you may use Cosmos DB to store Azure Spatial Anchor IDs, as outlined in the [ASA sharing sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-use-cosmos-db-to-store-anchors). But Cosmos DB has a [free tier](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/build-apps-for-free-with-azure-cosmos-db-free-tier/), so, depending on the scale of your project, that may be free as well.